# can $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(z)^n+f(z)^{n+1})$ grow forever?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(z)^n+f(z)^{n+1})dz$ go towards infinity as $n$ goes to infinity while $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(z)+f(z)^2)dz=1$ and any $n$ you pick bigger than or equal to $1$ converges to a finite value?$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(z)^n+f(z)^{n+1})dz<\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(z)^{n+1}+f(z)^{n+2})dz$$

My motivation for this problem is to understand what happens to functions that converge when you take an indefinite integral and then you take it to the power of a constant. I'm pretty sure that it has to stay finite for taking it to the power of something bigger than $1$ and I thought it might always shrink for most functions like $f(z)=e^{-x^2}$ then you take the indefinite integral you get $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ when you take it to the power of something like $100$ you get a smaller answer. So I slightly moved the powers and the function to see if it can grow forever.

Comment: What is the motivation behind this problem?

Comment: Is $0\in\Bbb N$? What did you try?

Comment: Just a clarifying question: by $f^2(z)$, do you mean $f(z)\cdot f(z)$ (i.e. multiplication) or $f(f(z))$ (i.e. iterated application)? I assume the former but thought I would check!

Comment: Is $f^n(x)$ here the $n$-the derivative or $n$-th power?

Comment: @Jason I mean $f(z) \times f(z)$

Comment: You should avoid this notation and use instead $f(z)^n$. It is completely unambiguous.

Comment: @dan_fulea no 0 is not an natural number here.

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for all $n$, i.e. do you mean to ask if there is an $f$ such that for all $n$, the equality holds?

Comment: Is this a better question?

Comment: @SuperWarm why did you delete this question?

Comment: If the end behaviour of the function is such that it diverges, then making it larger with a power and adding functions will surely make the integral grow larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  A very simple one is
$$f(x)=\begin {cases} 2& 0 \le x \lt \frac 16\\0&x \ge \frac 16 \end {cases}$$
I chose the $\frac 16$ to make $\int_0^\infty (f(x)+f(x)^2)dx=1$.  For any finite $n$ the integral converges but as $n$ increases the integral gets larger and larger.