# Does $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^n dx$ always shrink?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Does $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^n dx$ always shrink if $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx=1$ and $n$ is as large as you want.
This is similar to [can $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(z)^n+f(z)^{n+1})$ grow forever?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4166195/can-int-0-infty-fznfzn1-grow-forever) but I think this follows the guide lines. SuperWarm's motivation says that he/she wants to understand how taking a function that converges when you do the indefinite integral to the power of a large number $n$ changes the result of the indefinite integral. I found this interesting and I wonder if her/his thought that it would always shrink was true, But I couldn't find a proof of that it anywhere.

So are there functions that no matter how high $n$ is you can take the indefinite integral of $f(x)^n$ and it will grow, where $n>1$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx=1$ and $f(z)$ is differentiable everywhere.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^n dx>1$$

Comment: Take $f=2\chi_{[0,1/2]}$ where $\chi_{[0,1/2]}(x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ and $0$ otherwise. It seems like this is the universal counter example as per @Nicolas's comment ^^

Comment: $f(x)=2\cdot\mathrm{1}_{(0,1/2)}(x)$. EDIT: OK, same as @OlivierBégassat !!!

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Take $f$ to satisfy $f(x)$ to be a bounded function satisfying $\int_{x=0}^{1/3} f(x) = 2/3$, and then $f$ to be a continuous function on $(1/3,\infty)$ satisfying $\int_{1/3}^{\infty} f(x) = 1/3$, such that $f$ is continuous on the entire positive real line.
Then here $\int_0^{\infty}f^{n}(x)$ will grow with $n$ eventually.